# XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml throws error when parsing HTML containing nested tables

Tags: itext

I have some code that produces nested tables - essentially, financial reports produced using Apache Freemarker (http://freemarker.org/) which all works fine and renders and displays nicely. I wanted to export this to PDF using iText but I get this error:

com.itextpdf.tool.xml.exceptions.RuntimeWorkerException: Invalid nested tag table found, expected closing tag tr.

Is this not possible? Because of the way I produce the HTML, there's no way of changing this, although if there is a way I can parse the source

Comment: You can fix your HTML with JSoup before passing it on to iText.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but there's nothing wrong with the HTML, it renders fine in my browser. I tried Jsoup anyway but it didn't help.

Comment: Unfortunately "it renders fine in my browser" is not a good test. Browser do considerable efforts to fix broken HTML before rendering it. You can validate your HTML with the W3 Validator: https://validator.w3.org/ Upload or copy/paste your HTML and click "Check", then edit your question to add the validation report.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I am aware of that but it passes the W3,org validation so I am fairly certain it is fine - it is pretty simple HTML. Having rejigged it not to have nested table elements, it works fine now. It's just a pity that itext can't cope with that particular structure.

Comment: Please share your HTML. If deeply nested tables are involved, then there might be issues. Please try again with iText 7 + pdfHTML - it's HTML support is much improved compared to iText 5.